# Could you paraphrase it for me please?

Tags: paraphrasing

I cannot fully understand the bolded sentence. Thank you in advance.

> ***About the closest any* research has come to supporting the tiredness theory is to confirm** that adults yawn more often on weekdays than at weekends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. About is not a preposition here. It is an adverb whose meaning is close to "approximately". The research **seems to be** the closest and the writer is not 100% sure about it. That's why the adverb is used.
2. There is a noun and relative adverb omitted. That's why it is not easy to parse that part in bold. If you rephrase it to:

> About the closest (research) (where or that) any research has come to supporting the tiredness
>   theory is to confirm...

The relative adverb *where* or *that* is omitted as there is an antecedent (omitted research) that indicates where the action (any research has come...) happened. The following sentence has the same (or similar) structure.

> That house is the closest (house) (where or that) you can find a drinking water in this area.

The easier version would be

> There has been no research which was done exclusively to prove the theory (No research has been conducted to prove the theory). However, the closest
>   research that shows the relationship between yawning and tiredness is
>   to confirm that adults yawn more often on weekdays than at weekends,
>   and that school children yawn more frequently in their first year at
>   primary school than they do in kindergarten.

Comment: Is this also right:
about the closest research in which any research has come to supporting the tiredness theory is to conform ... .
I mean does "any research has come to supporting the tiredness theory " imply that INSIDE the closest research any research has come to supporting the tiredness theory?

Comment: @Alireza Yes. "in which" and "where" are usually interchangeable.